# Is "of which" always followed by "the"?

Tags: grammar, usage, definite-article

> I'm looking for a cap of which color is pink.

Someone told me that it is an ungrammatical sentence because after "of which" we always use "the".

So,

> I'm looking for a cap of which **the** color is pink.

would be right.

Is that true? Are there any examples about don't use "the" after "of which"?

Comment: I'm looking for a pink cap. The car was followed by a van whose colour was pink. The car was followed by a van the colour of which was pink. BUT this question is not appropriate on this website, kalrinz. ELL is intended to help with such basic English.

Answer (score 2):

> Someone told me that it is an ungrammatical sentence

They are right, the sentence is ungrammatical.

> because after "of which" we always use "the".

They are wrong, that is complete and utter nonsense. Observe:

> - You have ten apples, **of which some** are red.
> - I have three cars, **of which two** are fast.
> - Here are some umbrellas, **of which I** take five.
> - I hate cakes, **of which there** are just way too many in this world.
> - Over there is a house **of which it** is said it was built by Napoleon.
> - Fifty people live in my village, **of which women** attorneys are an integral part.
> - Color is not predictive **of which apple** will rot the fastest.
> - Klose is a phenomenon the likes **of which football** might not see again.

I could go on for hours, but you get the idea.

And yes, you might notice I included some red herrings with a completely different syntactical structure, but that's the whole point: they are *not* red herrings according to the "rule" you've been told. They show rather nicely just how oversimplified and nonsensical it really is.

And just to hammer the final nail into its coffin, here are the usage stats from the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) and the [British National Corpus (BNC)](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/):

```
                     COCA       BNC       sum

"of which"          30264     13038     43302
"of which the"       1119      1010      2129
 ratio in %             3.7       7.7       4.9
```

So in point of fact, in 92%+ of all cases, on either side of the Atlantic, "of which" is *not* followed by "the". Really, a much better rule would be the exact opposite of the one you've been told. At least it would nonsensically oversimplify in the right direction.

Seriously though, the reason why you have to use "the" in the original sentence has nothing to do with "of which", and indeed it has nothing to do with *anything* in that sentence — except for the "color" itself.

The only rule you have to apply here to decide which article to use is the rule you always apply to decide which article to use. That cap you are looking for has exactly one color. *The* color is pink. And that is all there is to it. You just can't say "Color of that cap is pink". You are missing an article. And that does not change if you move that bit from the main clause to the relative clause.

Oh, and last not least: "of which the color" sounds rather stilted. No one really talks like that. A native speaker in casual speech will likely opt for "whose color" instead,

> I'm looking for a cap whose color is pink.

but even more likely still, they will just say,

> I'm looking for a pink cap.

Answer (score -2):

You can say, I'm looking for a cap, which is the pink colored...

Comment: Yes, you can say that... but I don't think any proficient speaker will find it grammatical.